# unable to understand the output of this code snippet

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, while-loop, tuples

```
i = 1
while (i < 10): 
    i += 1
    print(i),
print(type(i)),
```

```
Output 

2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
<class 'int'>

Out[16]: (None,)
```

I am not able to understand why are we getting Out[16]: (None,) in the output when I am giving a comma after the last line.

Comment: I do not have `Out[16]: (None,)` when I run your code. Can you provide more code, or tell what IDE you are using.

Comment: The interpreter associates a comma `,` as the declaration of a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and since the `print()` function returns `None`, you end up with a tuple `(None,)` without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because the `print()` function returns `None`. Therefore, running

```
print(type(i)),
```

in your console is equivalent to running

```
None,
```

which outputs a tuple to the console, i.e.

```
(None,)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` returns `None`, which not displayed in a Notebook. Adding a comma turns the `None`into a tuple, which is displayed. A tuple with one element is always displayed with a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

`print(type(i)),` is a tuple consisting of one element, like `1,`, or `(1,)`.

`print` will return `None`, then you put that into the tuple, so you get `None,`, which is the same as `(None,)`